# Unable to change icon in phonegap apps

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to develop an android app using PhoneGap. I want to change the app icon and the splash screen images, which are always this default weird sheep:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLNLs.png

What I've done so far is to change the file "icon.png" in the root folder "AppName", and I've replaced all the images of `AppName\www\res\icon\android` and `AppName\www\res\screen\android` but it ALWAYS appears the same default image.

Can you, please, help me?

The code of config.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>AppName</name>
    <description>
        App description.
    </description>
    <author email="my@mail.com" href="http://www.website.com">
        S. B.
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it worked to change the images in \platforms\android\res\mipmap. There, I changed the image for all the resolutions.

Comment: Thanks, William. I did it more or less like that, but sometimes works, and sometimes it doesn't. What I've done is use "phonegap build android", then replace the files in "AppName\platforms\android\res\". But, if I want to change them again, I have to repeat the process and make sure that they've change in "AppName\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug". If not, I have to delete the files from "AppName\platforms\android\res\", type "phonegap build android", create the files again and re-type "phonegap build android". Looks weird, but it's actually working. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, thats weird. Idk right now what could solve that

Answer (score 0):

It is good to specify different path in config filestore all required images in that path.You can achive using cordova plugins.

Ref:https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

```
<platform name="android">
        <!--
            ldpi    : 36x36 px
            mdpi    : 48x48 px
            hdpi    : 72x72 px
            xhdpi   : 96x96 px
            xxhdpi  : 144x144 px
            xxxhdpi : 192x192 px
        -->
        <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    </platform>
```

Use cordova splash screen plugin 
// npm hosted (new) id
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen

// you may also install directly from this repo
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git

Ref : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this official Documentation [Phonegap Docs - Icons and Splash](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/#icons)